# Martingale with respect to different filtration

Tags: martingales, filtrations

I consider two stochastic processes $X_t = B_t$ and $Y_t = B_{t-1}$ with their natural filtrations $\mathcal{F}^X$ and $\mathcal{F}^Y$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

It is well known that $X_t$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}^X$ and $Y_t$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}^Y$.

Moreover, It is not difficult to show that $X_t$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}^Y$.

My question is: Is $Y_t$ a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}^X$?
I think that no, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: How is $Y$ defined for $t < 1$?

Comment: $(X_t)$ is not adapted to $\mathcal F^Y$, so it's not a martingale with repect to $\mathcal F^Y$.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice this fact!
What about my final question? Do you have any thoughts?